# ¿Por qué no funcionan mis comandos, cuando hago un modmail?

Tags: python, discord.py

Estoy haciendo un modmail y me he topado con un gran problema. A continuación les dejo el código:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


#PREFIJOS E INTENTS
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.guild_reactions = True
intents.guild_messages = True
intents.messages = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="x-",intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Listo")
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.playing, name="Dev = PingüiMaya14")) #CONFIGURA EL TEXTO DE LA ACTIVIDAD QUE ESTÁ HACIENDO

@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def react(ctx ):
    msg = await ctx.send("Hola")
    await msg.add_reaction("✅")


@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_role("ADMIN")
async def setup(ctx):
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    await guild.create_text_channel("mod-mail")
    msg = await ctx.send("Canal Creado - Configura los roles que tenga acceso en la configuración del chat")
    await msg.add_reaction("✅")



#modmail
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    empty_array = []
    modmail_channel = discord.utils.get(client.get_all_channels(), name="mod-mail")

    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if str(message.channel.type) == "private":
        if message.attachments != empty_array:
            files = message.attachments
            await modmail_channel.send("[" + message.author.display_name + "]")

            for file in files:
                await modmail_channel.send(file.url)
        else:
            await modmail_channel.send("[" + message.author.display_name + "] " + message.content)

    elif str(message.channel) == "mod-mail" and message.content.startswith("<"):
        member_object = message.mentions[0]
        if message.attachments != empty_array:
            files = message.attachments
            await member_object.send("[" + message.author.display_name + "]")

            for file in files:
                await member_object.send(file.url)
        else:
            index = message.content.index(" ")
            string = message.content
            mod_message = string[index:]
            await member_object.send("[" + message.author.display_name + "]" + mod_message)






client.run("TOKEN")
```

El modmail funciona y todo, el problema es que **los demás comandos no funcionan**.

Por ejemplo ahí hay dos comandos: `setup` y `react`. Cuando utilizo `x-react`  el bot ignora y no hace nada, y ahí debería escribir *hola* y reaccionar.

> He probado el mismo código sin el modmail y me funcionan los comandos, así que creo que el error está en la parte del modmail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para solucionarlo hay que añadir

```
await client.process_commands(message)
```

Al final de [on_message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working)